# PHP keep form values when running JS script function

Tags: javascript, php, function, checkbox

In a table it has a checkbox along with information in each row. When checkboxes are selected, I want it to run php related to the button and within it to call a JS function.

It calls the JS fine, but after that, it does not return to where it was and pick it up again as I still need to use the information within it when the JS has been ran. It's losing the checkboxes that were selected, and jumping out of it, whereas it's needed to keep the checkboxes selected and stay where it was.

Any help would be hugely appreciated as I've spent a long time trying different combinations to do it but not had much luck, to the point where I've even tried calling the js straight from the button and then selecting checkboxes after

'renameFile' is called from

```
<input type="submit" value="Rename" name="renameFile"/><br>
```

Then the php

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['renameFile']))  
{
    //uses checkboxes from table
    if(isset($_POST['checkbox']))
    {
        $checkedboxes = $_POST['checkbox'];
        $count = count($checkedboxes);
        if($count == 1)
        {
            foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $selected)
            {
                echo "<script> renameFile(); </script>";

                if($rename = $_GET['rename'])
                {
                    echo $rename;
            }
        }
```

JavaScript function

```
function renameFile()
{
var rename = prompt("Please enter a new name", "");

window.location.href="MainHomescreen.php?rename="+rename;
}
```

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve? Could you elaborate what you want it to do and what the problem is? I'm having a little difficulty understanding what it is that you want.

Comment: @Jezzabeanz Eventually, $rename will be used to rename a file on the server, but I figured a good place to start would be to just output the value got from the prompt to check it works and then build on it.

Comment: The first time the browser runs renameFile it loads that page (presumably the same page?) with no POST data. Probably you should try sending the rename command as an AJAX request, or encode the checkbox state in the URL and get them from $_GET.  Or use a session.

Comment: Ah using a session works perfectly it looks!